# Django adminsite: How to use reverse()?

Tags: django, django-admin

I hope my title is enough to understand my question

this is my admin.py

```
@admin.register(studentDiscount)
class studentDiscount(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Discount_Type','my_url_field')
    ordering = ('pk',)
def my_url_field(self, obj):
    obj_id = obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users.id

    url = reverse('record', args=[obj_id])
    return format_html(
        '<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{obj_id}</a>',
        url=url, obj_id=obj_id
    )
```

this is my model.py

```
class studentDiscount(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
```

this the result what I want

[image]

if I click on the **Download** link it will go to specific html by Student ID

this is the result if i click the Download link

[image]

this is the error I get with my current admin.py, please help me guys

[image]

this is my views.py

```
def record(request):
  return render(request, 'accounts/adminstudentrecord.html')
```

my url.py

```
path('record/', accounts.views.record, name='record'),
```

**UPDATE**

when i tried the answer of mr @ashish

[image]

but when I click the download link I get this error

[image]

this is my current admin.py

```
def my_url_field(self, obj):
    obj_id = obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users.id

    url = reverse('record', args=[obj_id])
    return format_html(
        "<a href='{url}' target='_blank'>Download</a>",
        url=url, obj_id=obj_id
    )
```

and this is my current url.py

```
path('record/<args>/', accounts.views.record, name='record'),
```

Comment: You are passing args in reverse url but in  this path('record/', accounts.views.record, name='record'), you are not accepting any argument. it should be like path('record/<args>/', accounts.views.record, name='record')

Comment: good day mr@ashish I tried your answer sir, and the error I get is """record() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'"""

Comment: can you post your answer mr?

Comment: Try changing your path('record/', accounts.views.record, name='record'), to path('accounts/record/', accounts.views.record, name='record'). I think it may help.. :)

Comment: the answer of mr @ashish 
nearly correct but when I click the download link this is the error I get  """record() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'"""

Comment: You should accept that arg from your function too: def record(request,args):
  return render(request, 'accounts/adminstudentrecord.html')

Comment: can you post your answer mr @ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('record/<args>/', accounts.views.record, name='record')
```

view.py

```
def record(request, args):
    return render(request, 'accounts/adminstudentrecord.html')
```